# Сортировка списков: получение элементов списка используя индексы из другого списка

Tags: python, списки

Задачей является построение минимальной выпуклой оболочки в поле с 40 точками. Благодаря алгоритму Грэхема я нашел номера вершин выпуклого многоугольника, которые записаны в список S (Например:4,2,15,1) . Также у меня есть список А с координатами всех 40 точек (Например: (100,250),(34,78)), номера вершин соответствуют индексам точек из этого списка. Мне надо узнать координаты вершин выпуклого многоугольника в определенном порядке как в списке S, чтобы можно было правильно их соединить (точки на экране появляются рандомно). У меня получилось найти координаты этих точек, но они выводятся не в правильном порядке.

```
for i in A:
    if A.index(i) in S:
        gran.append(i)
```

Т.е. если список S имеет элементы (4,2,15,1), то в конечном списке у меня будут координаты сначала точки 1 потом 2 и т.д.

Comment: не понял - если список S имеет элементы (4,2,15,1), то надо такие и достать в такой последовательности из A ?

Comment: этот список всегда разный, потому что координаты точек разные. Это я пример написал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, я ничего не понял, но чтобы достать элементымассива в нужном порядке, можно сделать так, воспользовавшись методом  itemgetter

```
A = [(100,250), (34,78), (1,2)]
S = [2,0,1]

from operator  import itemgetter
r = itemgetter(*S)(A)
print (r) # ((1, 2), (100, 250), (34, 78))
```

[**тут можно потренироваться**](https://eval.in/931424)

Comment: Благодарю Вас, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: отлично. удачи!

Answer (score 3):

`ans = [A[i] for i in S]` 
Если правильно понял